# Plotly graph not rendering on the side of other widgets: dash_bootstrap_components Row appears identical to Col

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm building a data explorer using dash, plotly, and dash bootstrap components. I would like a layout for my data to look something like:
[desired graph layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS9kf.png)
However, using dbc to slowly build up the interface, the graph keeps getting put on top of all the other widgets like so:
[rendered layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pms5k.png).

Here is a minimal working example to highlight the problem:

```py
sliders = dbc.Col(children=[
    'Iteration',
    dcc.Slider(id='iteration',min=0,max=1),
    'Frequency',
    dcc.Slider(id='frequency',min=0,max=1),
    'Depth log10(km)',
    dcc.Slider(id='depth',min=0,max=1),
    'Northing',
    dcc.Slider(id='north',min=0,max=1),
    'Easting',
    dcc.Slider(id='east',min=0,max=1),
    'Conductivity log10(km)',
    dcc.Slider(id='conductivity',min=0,max=1)])

controls = dbc.Col(children=[sliders],style={'width':'500px','borderWidth': '20px'})


app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
        dbc.Row(children=[dbc.Col(dcc.Graph()),controls]),
    ],
    fluid=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

To me it looks like `Row` behavior is exactly the same as `Col`. How do I get the graph figures to render on the side of the slider box?

I'm using:
python:
3.10.10

plotly: 5.14.0

dash: 2.9.2

dash_bootstrap_components: 1.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can should revise your code as below to make it work.

You can add width to your Col

```
app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                controls
            ], width={'size': 4}),
            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Graph()
            ], width={'size': 8}),            
        ]),
    ],
    fluid=False)
```

Or set style for `dbc.Row`.

```
app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                controls
            ]),
            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Graph()
            ]),            
        ],style={'display':'flex'}),
    ],
    fluid=False)
```

And you will get something like below:
[image]

Comment: That did it! So did adding an explicit width force the row behavior?

Comment: Yep, in a Row, there will be 12 Col so it is necessary to divide the width of the Col to fit Row.